# Libgdx sidebar menu

Tags: java, android, menu, libgdx, sidebar

I have red a lot of materials at this moment but I still can't find the answer. I'm trying to do this - 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7CSr.png

I don't have reputation to post pictures so i will try to explain. A side menu which will open on click (over the game screen) that has a text or buttons on it. It is supposed to be transparent or if it is not achiavable just some color. It needs to interact with the GameScreen. I did a research but i can't find something similar, some kind of table or something. Any idea on that question ?

Comment: To begin, you could use a ShapeRenderer for a rectangular menu. Then, you would need to add and remove listeners depending on the click state of the menu. The click state would also determine the alpha value of the menu and menu items.

Comment: Show us what have done already or what you have tried to do. You are not going to find out 'how' unless you try something by yourself and reading a lot of materials without actually practicing won't help.

Comment: Read up on scene2d.ui (Google it) and learn how to build your menu as shown in your picture. Then create a subclass of TemporalAction to modify the right side padding of a Table. Apply it to your table to animate the right padding between 0 and some negative value to hide and show your menu.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestions. I did some reading and did as you said. Created a button 

 myButton   = new MyButton(background); 

setting its position ---
myButton.setPosition();---

and adding it to a stage --- 
stage.addActor(myButton);---

after that I created a new batch with a shapreRender ---
 batch2 = new SpriteBatch();
shapeRenderer1.setProjectionMatrix(camera1.combined);

batch2.begin();
   myButton.draw(batch2, 1);

 batch2.end();---
The problem now is I cant set onlicklistener to it.

Comment: It is working, placing on top of the first screen and not moving with it. But when I try to set an onClickListener ----
myButton.addListener(new ChangeListener() {...
         ---- it doesn't work at all. Do you have any Idea why this is happening ? I did set the stage.act(); with delta time. Thank you very much everyone for the suggestions. You are very helpful to me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it looks like you haven't tried anything, I will only give you a rough logic of how its going to work.

You want to draw 'something' when the button is pressed. You can use a boolean to check if you want to show panel or not. In your render() method, you can put an if statement which would draw the menu in case showMenu == true. Menu is nothing more than a bunch of images that act as buttons when clicked on specified coordinates so it should be exactly same as drawing any other game element. In your InputProcessor, you can check if showMenu == true then check if the user clicked on any buttons on menu, otherwise if showMenu is not true, just skip the check for menu buttons. When the user presses the show/hide button again, change the showMenu boolean again from true to false or false to true.